# I get an error message before editing my code

Tags: python, boa-constructor

I work with boa constructor,I have a problem,when I change one or many parameters(border,columns,...) for a component graphically,I validate,then when I try to edit the code I get this message:

[image]

translation of the error message :the None values are valid only for the grapic editor
the generated source will be invalid out of the graphical editor it must be corrected before execution.
I get this error befor I run the application,I didn't edit the generated code :(

thanks for help

Comment: Can you add an English translation of that error for non-francophones?

Comment: Generated code should not be edited manualy because generator may not recognize code and you will not able edit it graphically again.

Comment: I didn't edit the generated code,this error occurs when I try to run the code @furas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If furas's translation of the error

> Generated code should not be edited manualy because generator may not recognize code and you will not able edit it graphically again.

is correct, you are getting that error because you are trying to edit code generated from a graphical UI designer.

When you use a graphic designer it has to generate code before the UI can be run. If you alter this generated code, it might work on this run, but the graphical design tool won't be able to reinterpret it and will **either refuse to allow you to edit the UI file** again, or even worse, **completely override any changes** you made when re-generating the UI code.

Instead consider importing the generated UI code, and making changes or overrides to subclasses of your UI widgets there, instead of in the generated code.